# Changing Ribbon Tab Name Throws Exception

Tags: c#, wpf

I tried to change the Tab Name like this:

```
foreach (Window window in Application.Current.Windows)
{
  (window as MainWindow).HomeTab.Header = "Teaching Learning Based Optimization";
}
```

However all I get is an NullReferenceException. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

P.S. Solved it! Did this:

```
if (window.GetType() == typeof(MainWindow))
{
  //Code
}
```

Thanks for the suggestions though.

Comment: Don't use `GetType()` for the overhead. Use `is` instead. This will also fail when `window` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

A null check at

```
(window as MainWindow)
```